# Class with multiple data inputs

Tags: python

New to utilizing classes.

If I have 3 different files as such:

```
#test1.txt:
a 100 xxx
b 200 fff
a 200 xxx
c 500 fff
a 200 www

test2.txt:
123 msg1 data2
123 msg1 data3
125 msg1 data2
123 msg2 data5
128 msg3 data2

test3.txt:
jan 5 79
jan 5 80
dec 5 79
dec 12 79
feb 5 80
```

and I want to populate all the data in 1 class while iterating through the files, is this the right approach?

I am having difficulty figuring out how to populate all of the data without overwriting and extracting based upon any single parameter.

```
class DInput:
    def set_f0(self, f0):
        self.f0=f0
        self.f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8=[]
    def add_f1(self, f1):
        self.f1.append(f1)
    def add_f2(self, f2):
        self.f2.append(f2)
    def add_f3(self, f3):
        self.f3.append(f3)
    def add_f4(self, f4):
        self.f4.append(f4)
    def add_f5(self, f5):
        self.f5.append(f5)
    def add_f6(self, f6):
        self.f6.append(f6)
    def add_f7(self, f7):
        self.f7.append(f7)
    def add_f8(self, f8):
        self.f8.append(f8)  

call = DInput() 

with open('test1.txt','r') as file1, open('test2.txt','r') as file2, open('test3.txt','r') as file3:
    for line in file1:
        f0,f1,f2=line.split()
        call.set_f0(f0)
        call.add_f1(f1)
        call.add_f2(f2)
    for line in file2:
        f3,f4,f5=line.split()
        call.add_f3(f3)
        call.add_f4(f4)
        call.add_f5(f5)
    for line in file3:
        f6,f7,f8=line.split()
        call.add_f6(f6)
        call.add_f7(f7)
        call.add_f8(f8)
```

Comment: `self.f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8=[]`
That won't do. It'll set only `f1` as object variable. The rest is local.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to do with the data, after populating? What's the big picture, how is the data going to be used later? Your data structure is most likely wrong, so the question of how to parse the data won't help you much.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `set_f0`, since you're overwriting `f0` on every iteration of the `for line in file1` loop. Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Christopher -1; after going through a few of your questions (a lot of which you've asked these past few days), it seems to me that you don't do a lot of research/debugging before posting to SO, particularly for problems that have simple runtime errors (like the one I pointed out). Put another way: your coding-fu needs work, from the basics, something that we can't really help you on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do, but it seems that you don't need classes at all.

I suppose that all your files have the same amount of lines and you are basically trying to merge them.

If that's your case, maybe you're looking for something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

files = ['test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt']

data = defaultdict(list)

for filename in files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            data[i].extend(line.split())
```

I've test it on your example files, and I got:

```
>>> for i in sorted(data):
...      print(data[i])
['a', '100', 'xxx', '123', 'msg1', 'data2', 'jan', '5', '79']
['b', '200', 'fff', '123', 'msg1', 'data3', 'jan', '5', '80']
['a', '200', 'xxx', '125', 'msg1', 'data2', 'dec', '5', '79']
['c', '500', 'fff', '123', 'msg2', 'data5', 'dec', '12', '79']
['a', '200', 'www', '128', 'msg3', 'data2', 'feb', '5', '80']
```

Comment: I thought he may want to have a quasi-three-dimensional space where one dimension is file, second dimension is column, and third dimension is line. It looks like that to me, but I have no clue... Your approach definitely does something different than his, but I agree that it's unclear what the result needs to be.

Comment: @Irfy: My crystal ball is a little cloudy tonight so I wouldn't know. I thought that with all those `f_i` the OP was just looking at every column on its own, but hey.. who knows?

Comment: @jcollado and rik poggi: this makes much more sense; suppose i was overcomplicating the problem.  however, i am trying to understand when a class should be used as opposed to a list or dictionary and how to properly populate a class with multiple data sets.  sorry for the poor example.

Comment: @Christopher: What does "populate a class with multiple data sets" means?  Wouldn't that just be an object with a `dict` attribute? Wouldn't you populate such `dict` with something like what we've shown here? (The proper method would really depends on what you're going to do with that data). Don't get me wrong, but judging from your code you have more pressing issues, you need to be able to write code that works, and then you'll have the tools to worry about which design would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you're getting and setting your data is more complex than needed. For example, to get all the elements to set for each instance object in a list I would the the following:

```
from itertools import izip, chain

files = [open('test{0}.txt'.format(i)) for i in range(1,4)]
for lines in izip(*files):
    lines = chain.from_iterable([line.strip().split()
                                 for line in lines])
    print list(lines)
```

Example output:

```
['a', '100', 'xxx', '123', 'msg1', 'data2', 'jan', '5', '79']
['b', '200', 'fff', '123', 'msg1', 'data3', 'jan', '5', '80']
['a', '200', 'xxx', '125', 'msg1', 'data2', 'dec', '5', '79']
['c', '500', 'fff', '123', 'msg2', 'data5', 'dec', '12', '79']
['a', '200', 'www', '128', 'msg3', 'data2', 'feb', '5', '80']
```